# how to get `PathInterpolator` which is written in xml from kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I defined `PathInterpolator` in xml as

```
<pathInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:controlX1="0.4"
    android:controlY1="0"
    android:controlX2="1"
    android:controlY2="1"/>
```

How can i get that `interpolator` from `kotlin`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can load it as any other `Interpolator` from `.xml`.

```
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils

//...
AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(context, R.interpolator.you_file)
```